# How to use JavaFX in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-kepler

I did some research that says JavaFX is included in JDK 7. I'm using the latest version of the JDK. As far as I know, I'm using the latest version of Eclipse. However, whenever i start typing "import javax.", nothing shows up, even after I push the button to get suggestions.
How do i get javafx to work?

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX is part of the Java7 download but not part of the classpath. You need to use an extra plugin inside Eclipse to write JavaFX applications on Java7.

http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html and follow http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1 to get started.